# How do I change the options that appear in the generated Grub 0.97 menu.lst file?

Tags: 10.04, grub-legacy

I'm working on systems that have 10.04.3 installed as an upgrade from 8.04. So these systems have Grub 0.97 installed.

I want to get verbose console output during startup, so I want to eliminate the "quiet" option being passed to the kernel by the generated Grub menu options. I see there's a commented option in the /boot/grub/menu.lst file:

```
## additional options to use with the default boot option, but not with the
## alternatives
## e.g. defoptions=vga=791 resume=/dev/hda5
# defoptions=quiet splash
```

I know edits to the menu.lst would be lost upon the next 'update-grub'. So where, or what, do I set so that a subsequent 'update-grub' invocation will build the menu.lst file the way I want?

I have some newer systems (10.04 and 12.04 clean installs) that have an /etc/default/grub file, but my Grub 0.97 systems don't have that file. Could I just create it and add

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""
```

to get what I want (no "quiet" arg to the kernels) in menu.lst?

Comment: ...and why can't I tag this either simply "grub", (my tag turns into a "grub2" tag,) or "grub-0.97"?

Comment: grub legacy is no longer supported in Ubuntu.  10.04 is the last ot use grub legacy, as far as I am aware.

Comment: ...which helps me how? :)

Comment: I was only trying to answer your comment.  not answer your question.

Comment: re tag: Oh, well, yes then that's helpful (not being sarcastic.) I still think it would make sense to have a grub0.97 tag -- but I see why there isn't one. Thanks!

Comment: I created the `grub-legacy` tag, but it could be deleted in future, unless I can argue for WHY it should stay.

Comment: Implicitly supported until 10.04 EOL -- people have 10.04 installed as legit upgrades from 8.04. IMO think it's ok to have tags for things that aren't supported any more. But, this is way down the rabbit hole... so unimportant in the grand scheme. :^)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

...turns out that for Grub 0.97 (ie Grub legacy) you just edit the config file in place. So I went into '/boot/grub/menu.lst' and changed the

```
# defoptions=quiet splash
```

to

```
# defoptions=splash
```

and then ran 'update-grub'.

Yes, the 'defoptions' line is a comment in the menu.lst file. After update-grub all my kernel boot options no longer had the 'quiet' argument.

Answer (score 0):

Use grub-customizer, it is a GUI tool to edit list configuration, timeout and appearance settings

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

Comment: what does grub-customizer specifically manipulate/edit?

Comment: read my answer again please

Comment: I did. These are headless servers. I meant, what file(s) does that customizer manipulate. I suppose I could d/l the package and dig through it.